# Write Marshalled multiple objects into one xml file

Tags: java, jaxb

I am working in create simple student details task for my practice.

I have the following class as StudentModel

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlType(name = "StudentDetails",propOrder = { "studentName",  "fatherName", "rollNumber", "studentAge",
        "studentGender", "studentDOB", "addressLine1", "addressLine2", "city",
        "state", "country", "zipcode" })
public class StudentModel {

    @XmlElement
    private String studentName;
    @XmlElement
    private String fatherName;
    @XmlAttribute
    private int rollNumber;
    @XmlElement
    private int studentAge;
    @XmlElement
    private String studentGender;
    @XmlElement
    private String studentDOB;
    @XmlElement
    private String addressLine1;
    @XmlElement
    private String addressLine2;
    @XmlElement
    private String city;
    @XmlElement
    private String state;
    @XmlElement
    private String country;
    @XmlElement
    private int zipcode;

    }
```

Following code i used to create xml file from java objects

```
if( xml.exists() ){
        try {

            fr4 = new FileReader(file);
            br4 = new BufferedReader(fr4);

            while( (readFile = br4.readLine()) != null ){   

            line = new Scanner(readFile).useDelimiter(",");

            StudentModel toXml = new StudentModel(line.next(),line.next(),  Integer.parseInt(line.next()),
                                Integer.parseInt(line.next()), line.next(), line.next(), line.next(), line.next(),
line.next(), line.next(), line.next(), Integer.parseInt(line.next()));

            JAXBContext context;
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentModel.class);
            Marshaller marshal = context.createMarshaller();
            marshal.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                                Boolean.TRUE);

            fw2 = new FileWriter(xml, true);
            marshal.marshal(toXml, fw2);
        }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }else{
            System.out.println("File not created");
        }
```

My problem is i couldn't make multiple objects into one file and the output is look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StudentModel>
    <studentName>peter</studentName>
    <fatherName>john</fatherName>
    <rollNumber>12</rollNumber>
    <studentAge>24</studentAge>
    <studentGender>m</studentGender>
    <studentDOB>16-06-1991</studentDOB>
    <addressLine1>ty</addressLine1>
    <addressLine2>yt</addressLine2>
    <city>new york</city>
    <state>ny</state>
    <country>us</country>
    <zipcode>456123</zipcode>
</StudentModel>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StudentModel rollNumber="11">
    <studentName>john</studentName>
    <fatherName>peter</fatherName>
    <studentAge>24</studentAge>
    <studentGender>M</studentGender>
    <studentDOB>02-10-1991</studentDOB>
    <addressLine1>line1</addressLine1>
    <addressLine2>line2</addressLine2>
    <city>washington</city>
    <state>dc</state>
    <country>us</country>
    <zipcode>123456</zipcode>
</StudentModel>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about creating a class on top and add a list of StudentModels to it. So the new class would be the root

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
public class Student{
  List<StudentModel> studentModels;
}
```

And xml would be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Student>
<StudentModel>
    <studentName>peter</studentName>
    <fatherName>john</fatherName>
    <rollNumber>12</rollNumber>
    <studentAge>24</studentAge>
    <studentGender>m</studentGender>
    <studentDOB>16-06-1991</studentDOB>
    <addressLine1>ty</addressLine1>
    <addressLine2>yt</addressLine2>
    <city>new york</city>
    <state>ny</state>
    <country>us</country>
    <zipcode>456123</zipcode>
</StudentModel>
<StudentModel rollNumber="11">
    <studentName>john</studentName>
    <fatherName>peter</fatherName>
    <studentAge>24</studentAge>
    <studentGender>M</studentGender>
    <studentDOB>02-10-1991</studentDOB>
    <addressLine1>line1</addressLine1>
    <addressLine2>line2</addressLine2>
    <city>washington</city>
    <state>dc</state>
    <country>us</country>
    <zipcode>123456</zipcode>
</StudentModel>
</Student>
```

Comment: thanks for your response @awsome  and done it as you said. but my xml doesn't properly added the objects values into xml

Comment: what do you mean by properly added

Comment: I rectify it.  i mean that java objects in the list are not displayed correctly in browser.